# Cannot clone array of objects in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make my burger work, unfortunately I found a problem that I don't know how to resolve or why is not working... PLEASE HEEEELP!!!

The idea in the project is to start with a set of ingredients pre-defined, price and initial amount... ex in my mind, all burgers must have lettuce and meat... so I created the object called ORIGINALBURGER, the when creating the class, using the constructor assign the ORIGINALBURGER to the state by cloning the original object

The problem: I cannot clone my original burger object using spread or any other method.  Every time I do update the state "ingredientes", it also modify my original object...

Am I missing something? Please check my code below and THANKS for helping this newbie:

```js
        import React, { Component } from "react";
import Aux from "../../hoc/Aux";
import Burguer from "../../components/Burguer/Burguer";
import BuildControls from "../../components/Burguer/BuildControls/BuildControls";

const OriginalIngredients = [
  { PublicName: "Salad", Type: "salad", Quantity: 1, Price: 0.65 },
  { PublicName: "Bacon", Type: "bacon", Quantity: 0, Price: 1.65 },
  {
    PublicName: "American Cheese",
    Type: "cheese",
    Quantity: 0,
    Price: 0.99
  },
  { PublicName: "Meat Patty", Type: "meat", Quantity: 1, Price: 2.65 }
];

class BurguerBuilder extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      // ---> OPTION B ---> ingredientes: ORIGINALBURGUER.map(a => ({ ...a })),
      ingredientes: [...OriginalIngredients],
      TotalPrice: 0
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { ingredientes } = this.state;

    return (
      <Aux>
        <Burguer ingredients={ingredientes} />
        <BuildControls
          ingredients={ingredientes}
          AddIngredientEvent={this.handleAddIngredient}
          RemoveIngredientEvent={this.handleRemoveIngredient}
          changeAmtEvent={this.handleIngredientChangeAmt}
          ResetIngredientsEvent={this.hanldeResetIngredients}
        />
      </Aux>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const TotalBurguerPrice = this.CalculateBurguerPrice();
    this.setState({ TotalPrice: TotalBurguerPrice });
  }

  CalculateBurguerPrice() {
    return 50;
  }

  hanldeResetIngredients = () => {
    const IngredientesOriginales = [...OriginalIngredients];
    this.setState({ ingredientes: IngredientesOriginales });
  };

  handleRemoveIngredient = type => {
    const ingredientes = [...this.state.ingredientes];
    if (ingredientes.find(f => f.Type === type).Quantity > 0)
      ingredientes.find(f => f.Type === type).Quantity--;
    this.setState({ ingredientes });
  };

  handleAddIngredient = type => {
    const ingredientes = [...this.state.ingredientes];
    ingredientes.find(f => f.Type === type).Quantity++;
    this.setState({ ingredientes });
    console.log("state content", this.state.ingredientes);
    console.log("original burger", OriginalIngredients);
  };

  handleIngredientChangeAmt = (evento, tipo) => {
    const ingredientes = [...this.state.ingredientes];
    const ingrediente = ingredientes.find(i => i.Type === tipo);

    if (evento.target.value === "") ingrediente.Quantity = 0;
    else if (evento.target.value >= 0)
      ingrediente.Quantity = evento.target.value;
    else ingrediente.Quantity = 0;

    this.setState({ ingredientes });
  };
}

export default BurguerBuilder;
```

For example, in the method called **hanldeResetIngredients** I would like to assign the original version of my object to the current state, but when I see, both the state and the original object have changed.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Spread is creating a shallow copy, meaning that it loops through your array and copies over the references to the objects in that array rather than actually copying each object. You need to loop over your array and spread each object ie:

```
OriginalIngredients.map( (ingredient) => {
    return {...ingredient}
});
```